# Extract All Values using HTMLAligity Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

Following is the HTML of webpage and I am willing to extract values of All data-user-id field

```
<div class="account   js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable " data-screen-name="ducttape" data-user-id="817977">
<div class="account   js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable " data-screen-name="adage" data-user-id="12480582">
```

can any one pls provide help is c# or vb.net I tried following code but its not working

```
Dim UrlRegister1 As String = "C:/Users/Shripad/Desktop/result.htm"
   Dim document = New HtmlDocument()
    document.Load("C:/Users/Shripad/Desktop/result.htm")
    Dim node As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//class='account   js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable'/data-user-id=")
    Dim useridd As String = node.Attributes("Value").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting elements that has 'account' class - use XPath contains selector like this:

```
[contains(@class, 'account')]
```

The whole result should be:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//div[contains(@class, 'account')]");
var useridd = node.Attributes["data-user-id"].Value;
```

Here more information about selecting element by classes : [XPath for CSS classes](http://cowburn.info/2009/06/15/xpath-css-class/)